# Count the different values row-wise and each result as an extra column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As can be seen from my title, I have a pandas dataframe with different columns and rows. I want to do a row by row count of the contained values. I want to add the count result for each value in a new column.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
  2     2    1
  1     1    1
  3     1    2
```

And this is how the result should look like:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Count1  Count2  Count3
  2     2    1      1        2      0
  1     1    1      3        0      0
  3     1    2      1        1      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `value_counts` on index axis:

```
df1 = (df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1)
         .fillna(0).astype(int).add_prefix('Count'))
out = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Count1  Count2  Count3
0     2     2     1       1       2       0
1     1     1     1       3       0       0
2     3     1     2       1       1       1
```

Comment: This is working. But I dont understand why you do you use fillna?

Comment: Because for row 0, you have no 3 so the result is undefined. I prefer to set to 0 because the count is 0. Now I can convert to int to avoid 2.0, 1.0, 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
# stack values and get rid of column names
s = df.stack().droplevel(1)

# compute a cross-tab, rename columns, join to original
out = df.join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s).add_prefix('Count'))
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Count1  Count2  Count3
0     2     2     1       1       2       0
1     1     1     1       3       0       0
2     3     1     2       1       1       1
```

Alternative with [`groupby.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.value_counts.html) (likely less efficient):

```
out = df.join(df.stack()
                .groupby(level=0).value_counts()
                .unstack(level=1, fill_value=0)
                .add_prefix('Count')
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all of the unique values in the dataframe, creating a column for each that gives the count per row of that value.

```
for v in np.unique(df):
    df[f'Count{v}'] = (df == v).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: This seems to work but gives the wrong count of every value